# How to let a user become a fan of a page through Facebook Connect on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I'm creating an iPhone App that uses facebook connect to enable the user to post messages to a specific fan page. I also want to allow my users to become a fan of the page through Facebook Connect but I can't find a way to do this.

So: is it possible to create a "become a fan"-button in an iPhone app using Facebook Connect? Which API call should I make?

If it's not possible in Facebook Connect directly, any suggestions for a workaround (for instance via some PHP code on my server)?

thanks,
Thomas

Comment: I've seen that the Facebook fanbox widget uses the url http://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fan_status.php to post to. Has anyone got experience using this service? 

I guess there's no chance I could use this page together with the current user token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible yet (and maybe won't ever be possible). Is a protection for the user.

You can check if someone is fan of a page but not add it as a fan.

Answer (score 1):

thomas,
you can use an uiwebview and one of facebooks like buttons via iframe (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). The problem is, that the user needs to authenticate on facebook within your app, such that his login credentials are known. This should be done before presenting the like button. I've done this in an app called istockcharts.

An API call for liking something is not planned by facebook, yet.